# Is timer instance can be reused in java?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, timer, timertask

In the following code is it possible to reuse the same timer1 object again instead of timer2 for invoking timertask?

```
            Timer timer1 = new Timer();

        timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PriorityQueueHandler.getQueueInstance().addToQueue(passengers.get(counter));
            counter++;
            if(counter == passengers.size()){
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }, DELAY, ARRIVAL_INTERVAL);

    PriorityQueueHandler.getQueueInstance().print();

    Timer timer2 = new Timer();

    timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            PriorityQueueHandler.getQueueInstance().print();
        }
    }, DELAY, BOOKING_INTERVAL);
```

Comment: Well, what happens if you *try it*?

Answer (score 3):

You can reuse a timer instance for several tasks. Notice that a timer executes all tasks in one single thread synchronous which means that if one task is stalled this will affect the other tasks scheduled on the same timer, i.e. the other task will not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should be fine - *if* you're happy with the tasks running sequentially. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.

It's fine to have many scheduled tasks:

> Implementation note: This class scales to large numbers of concurrently scheduled tasks (thousands should present no problem). Internally, it uses a binary heap to represent its task queue, so the cost to schedule a task is O(log n), where n is the number of concurrently scheduled tasks.

Personally I'd probably use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to give more control over the threads created and concurrency between tasks, but that's a slightly different matter.